# PHP XML and nodes with same name

Tags: php, xml

I am having some difficulty wrapping my brain around this, since I am new to PHP.

XML Document contains:

```
<containerDetails>
    <ID> theid </id>
     <OwnerDetails id = 23212>
          <name> the name </name>
     </OwnerDetails>
     <OtherData> 
           asdfdsa
     </OtherData>
</containerDetails>
```

And I can access The Owner Name via `$current["OwnerDetails"]["Name"]` ok

However sometimes there are multiple ownerdetails:

```
<containerDetails>
    <ID> theid </id>
     <OwnerDetails id = 23212>
          <name> the name </name>
     </OwnerDetails>
     <OwnerDetails id = 23233>
          <name> other name </name>
     </OwnerDetails>
     <OtherData> 
           asdfdsa
     </OtherData>
</containerDetails>
```

I can use a

```
foreach($current["OwnerDetails"] as $row) 
    echo $row["Name"]
```

and I see both names.  But if there is only ONE OwnerDetails it won't display the name correctly....  How Do I reliably access this data even if I don't know if there will be one or multiple items?

Comment: Are you able to change the structure of the xml? It would seem the details should have their own container.

Comment: Is the XML provided a true representation of the XML you're working with? I only ask because it's invalid - tag mismatch with `ID`/`id`, and missing quotes around the ID attributes. The native XML parsers wouldn't be any use if so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with this might be something like the following, depending on your XML parsing library:

```
// make sure you have an array containing OwnerDetails elements
$ownerDetails = isset($current["OwnerDetails"][0])
              ? $current["OwnerDetails"]
              : array($current["OwnerDetails"]);

// now iterate over it
foreach ($ownerDetails as $row) {
    echo $row["Name"];
}
```

However, [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) can take care of this for you; SimpleXMLElement objects implement the Traversable interface, so you could use `foreach` in either scenario.

Comment: Actually, I think there is a flaw in this approach, because we know that `$current["OwnerDetails"]` must always be an array for `$current["OwnerDetails"]["Name"]` to work. Replace the `is_array(...)` with `isset($current["OwnerDetails"][0])` and this will probably work with the current parser.

Comment: Good point, seems my answer was a bit rushed; I'll get it updated. I agree that without knowing the library that this might be a better option, but SimpleXML would probably be neater in this scenario.

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you.  I was able to access all child nodes using this (ie: $row["spec"]["volume"] )For anyone reading this later on I should add it was SimpleXML and no, I cannot change the incoming (not 100% perfect) structure of the incoming data, and this did the trick.  Much Appreciated!

Comment: @DanFlood This is most certainly *not* SimpleXML. It may have been created using SimpleXML as an intermediate step, but the above code will not work on a SimpleXML object.

Comment: Instead of `isset` in this case it would be more precise to use `is_array`.

Comment: @hakre see the first comment from IMSoP, and the first version of the answer — it'd be an array in both cases. The alternative to the above would be to check `isset($current["OwnerDetails"]["Name"])` or similar.

Comment: @cbuckley: Sure, the check needs to be as deep as with `isset` because of that badly desgined XML parser that removes a lot of infomration while punching things into borken arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what XML parsing function you're using, so it's hard to debug its precise behaviour.

If you use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml), then `foreach ( $current->OwnerDetails as $row )` should work in both cases. Similarly, both `$current->OwnerDetails->Name` and `$current->OwnerDetails[0]->Name` will get you the `Name` of the first child. SimpleXML overloads functionality to work smoothly in cases like this.

Note the `->` notation (property access) to refer to a child node. In SimpleXML, the `['string']` notation accesses attributes, e.g. `$current->OwnerDetails['id']`.